# node.js add method(or function) to a object - unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

While I study node.js, I created a object that contains a method

```js
var users = [{
    name: 'aa',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'bb',
    age: 20
  }
];

users.push(
  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;

  }
);

console.log(users[2](10, 10));


var add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

users.push(add);


console.log(users[3](10, 10));
```

First, I created an object called 'users' and I tried adding a function called 'add'. as you can see, I tried 2 ways. first one is adding a method when pushing, and the second one is adding after I allocate a method to variable.

First one doesn't work while second one works. I'm wondering if there is any difference between these.

Thank you

Comment: both works for me.

Comment: both are working... What's the issue?

Comment: First of all "created a object that contains a method" - in current example you create array with objects and then you add functions to array, not an object with method.
Also your example works fine and you can try it by using "Run code snippet" button. Try post complete code part or show another example

Comment: i am learning node.js with brackets, and when i use first one, it says unexpected identifier